# I cannot go to the page I want

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

Hello I have a post blog where I have a homepage with posts and if you click on it you are redirected to the post_detail page. Now I want the users to allow to delete their comments which I achieved but I want them to stay on the same post_detail page. I could not come over it and hope that someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

post_detail.html

```
<div class="container">
<br>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">{{post.post}} </h1>
<p style="font-size:small;text-align:center;">{{post.created_on}}</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Yorum At</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% for i in commentmodel_list%}
<h4 >{{i.comment}}</h4>
{% if i.author_security == user%}
<a style="float:right;color:red;"href="{% url 'forum:delete' slug=post.slug comment_id=i.id %}"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
{% endif %}
{% if i.author is none %}
<p style="font-size:small;">Anonim | {{i.created_on}}</p>
{% else%}
<p style="font-size:small;"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">@{{i.author}}</a> | {{i.created_on}}</p>
{% endif %}

<hr>
<br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

```
app_name='forum'

urlpatterns=[
     path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='post'),
     path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
     path('delete/<slug:slug>/<comment_id>/',views.delete_post,name='delete')
]
```

views.py

```
def delete_post(request,slug=None,comment_id=None):
    comment_delete=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    comment_delete.delete()
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return redirect('forum:post_detail', slug= post)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to delete the comments via submitting a [POST request with CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/), otherwise it's prone to [CSRF attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). When you'll be submitting the form, you can add there an input with a value representing the current page which you'll redirect to afterwards. Pseudocode:

```
<form action="{% url 'forum:delete' slug=post.slug comment_id=i.id %}" 
method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="current_post" value="{{ post.slug }}">
<input type="submit>
</form>
```

view:

```
def delete_post(request, comment_id=None):
    Comment.objects.filter(id=comment_id).delete()
    return redirect('forum:post_detail', slug= request.POST['current_post'])
```

It's not obvious if by "I want them to stay on the same post_detail page" you mean that you dont want to perform the redirect in browser and you'd rather delete it via ajax. If that's the case, please check the [Django documentation about AJAX request with CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax), as there's an example how to do exactly that.

Comment: yes I want them to stay on the same page I will read the documentation, but have you an idea how I could get it done on my project?

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü right. And which part of the linked Django documentation about how to do exactly this is not clear enough?